# Agora's Video Call Layout

Tags: android, video, sdk, call, agora.io

**SDK**: Agora Video Call 
**Platform**: TV 
**OS**: Android 
**Problem**: I recently integrated Agora's video call service into our app, whenever I launch a video call, the layout seems to be unorganized, new entries were added vertically. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

**Reference**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nq5d5PK4HyMZ6-XdXvhTOGeJFeOxuvmp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show us what have you done so far

Comment: You can find detailed description about layout setting in [the official doc](https://docs.agora.io/en/2.0/product/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/live_video_android?platform=Android) `setVideoCompositingLayout `.

Comment: May I ask which Smart TV or TV BOX are you using? Does it have a built in camera? Which camera model are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are building app with Agora RTC SDK(Video + Interactive Broadcasting SDK) or just launch Agora Video Call(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.agora.vcall) in your app?

If the former case, you can totally control the UI by your code logic. If the latter one, can you help to take a picture for us, we can check if need some enhancements for UI on TV.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes I'm currently developing with Agora RTC SDK. I also checked the official Agora from the playstore. And it seems what I need to achieve is the one thats in the playstore, I'm going to try and play with the SDK, still, layouts are deranged and i cant figure it out

Comment: For UI view, you can refer https://github.com/AgoraIO/OpenVideoCall-Android Good luck